# I need schematic of this simple microphone

Tags: microphone

wires inside the  microphone were cut and I don't know the correct place of wires to solder them so I need schematic  or your explanation to repair this microphone.

This microphone contains only four items;  switch, 2.2kohm resistor, microphone capsule and 1.5v battery.
The microphone has three cut wires:two of these wires connected to jack. and third wire is connected to negative terminal of 1.5 v battery and positive terminal of battery connects to microphone capsule.And another side of microphone capsule connected to microphone body.

The  switch of the microphone has three pins and one side of a 2.2 kohm resistor connected to center pin of switch and other side of resistor connected to body of switch.A side pin of switch doesn't have any solder,it seems any wire weren't connected to this pin.
[image of microphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q13sx.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A battery, 2.2k resistor, microphone element are three components found in an **electret microphone**. However, the usual voltage source is higher than that provided by a 1.5V battery:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw61Jq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Polarity of this microphone element matters: you should identify its grounded connection for proper operation. It appears that the capacitor C1 is not included. In that case, the junction of the microphone element and 2k resistor(R1) would go directly to the jack's tip.
**Edit:**
Battery positive goes directly to microphone? Then the following circuit would be likely:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGOrWO.png)</sup>

Where's the switch? Hard to say. Likely in series with the battery, to reduce current (and allow the battery to last longer).

Comment: Thanks.why is there some differences between schematic and my microphone?for example in your schematic battery negative connected directly to microphone element but in my case battery positive connected directly to microphone element. And also there is no switch in your schematic!

Comment: @Nima Another circuit arrangement edited in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for new circuit.That's correct and new circuit is similar to my case.It seems switch series with battery negative in my case.when switch on microphone works and when switch off,only 2.2k resistor is active in circuit.Is this true?